# Make list items overlap one another in a specific way (sequence)

Tags: html, css

So I don't really know how to explain this in words. But this is what I'm trying to achieve 
[image]

and this is what I've done so far [**link**](http://jsfiddle.net/r0L0nty2/)

```css
ul.quicktabs-tabs li {
  float: left;
  height: 20px;
  margin: 0;  
  margin-right:-20px;
  padding: 0; 
  width:150px;
  background: transparent;
}

ul.quicktabs-tabs li a {
  font-family: inherit;
  margin: 0;
  display: block; 
  padding: 10px 27px 10px 7px;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #6da648 !important;
  border: 2px solid #6da648;
  border-radius: 6px;
  margin: 0;
  background:#fff;
}
ul.quicktabs-tabs li.active a, ul.quicktabs-tabs li.active a:hover {
  color: #fff !important;
  background-position: right -20px;
  background: #6da648;
}
ul.quicktabs-tabs {
  margin: 0 0 10px 0; 
  font-size: 11px; 
  list-style: none;
  padding: 1px 23px 23px 0;
}
```

```html
<ul class="quicktabs-tabs">
    <li class="active"><a href="#">Item 1</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Item 2</a></li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`<li>` element at the right overlaps `<li>` element at the left. Set `z-index` and `position` of the element with class `active` to prevent that overlapping, adjust some paddings and margins.

```css
ul.quicktabs-tabs li {
  float: left;
  height: 20px;
  margin: 0;  
  margin-right:-8px;
  padding: 0; 
  width:150px;
  background: transparent;
}

ul.quicktabs-tabs li a {
  font-family: inherit;
  margin: 0;
  display: block; 
  padding: 10px 27px 10px 12px;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #6da648 !important;
  border: 2px solid #6da648;
  border-radius: 6px;
  margin: 0;
  background:#fff;
}
ul.quicktabs-tabs li.active a, ul.quicktabs-tabs li.active a:hover {
  color: #fff !important;
  background-position: right -20px;
  background: #6da648;
  z-index: 1000;
  position: relative;
}
ul.quicktabs-tabs {
  margin: 0 0 10px 0; 
  font-size: 11px; 
  list-style: none;
  padding: 1px 23px 23px 0;
}
```

```html
<ul class="quicktabs-tabs">
    <li><a href="#">Item 0</a></li>
    <li class="active"><a href="#">Item 1</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Item 2</a></li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

I create a progress bar using [css3 progress bar](http://css-tricks.com/css3-progress-bars/) guide:

```css
  .meter {
      height: 40px;
      /* Can be anything */
      position: relative;
      margin: 60px 0 20px 0;
      /* Just for demo spacing */
      -moz-border-radius: 25px;
      -webkit-border-radius: 25px;
      border-radius: 25px;
      -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 -1px 1px rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.3);
      -moz-box-shadow : inset 0 -1px 1px rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.3);
      box-shadow : inset 0 -1px 1px rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.3);
      border: solid 1px orange;
  }
  .meter > span {
      display: block;
      height: 100%;
      -webkit-border-top-right-radius: 8px;
      -webkit-border-bottom-right-radius: 8px;
      -moz-border-radius-topright: 8px;
      -moz-border-radius-bottomright: 8px;
      border-top-right-radius: 8px;
      border-bottom-right-radius: 8px;
      -webkit-border-top-left-radius: 20px;
      -webkit-border-bottom-left-radius: 20px;
      -moz-border-radius-topleft: 20px;
      -moz-border-radius-bottomleft: 20px;
      border-top-left-radius: 20px;
      border-bottom-left-radius: 20px;
      background-color: rgb(43, 194, 83);
      background-image: -webkit-gradient(linear, left bottom, left top, color-stop(0, rgb(43, 194, 83)), color-stop(1, rgb(84, 240, 84)));
      background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(center bottom, rgb(43, 194, 83) 37%, rgb(84, 240, 84) 69%);
      -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 2px 9px rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.3), inset 0 -2px 6px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4);
      -moz-box-shadow: inset 0 2px 9px rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.3), inset 0 -2px 6px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4);
      box-shadow: inset 0 2px 9px rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.3), inset 0 -2px 6px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4);
      position: relative;
      overflow: hidden;
  }
  .meter > span:after, .animate > span > span {
      content:"";
      position: absolute;
      top: 0;
      left: 0;
      bottom: 0;
      right: 0;
      background-image: -webkit-gradient(linear, 0 0, 100% 100%, color-stop(.25, rgba(255, 255, 255, .2)), color-stop(.25, transparent), color-stop(.5, transparent), color-stop(.5, rgba(255, 255, 255, .2)), color-stop(.75, rgba(255, 255, 255, .2)), color-stop(.75, transparent), to(transparent));
      background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(-45deg, rgba(255, 255, 255, .2) 25%, transparent 25%, transparent 50%, rgba(255, 255, 255, .2) 50%, rgba(255, 255, 255, .2) 75%, transparent 75%, transparent);
      z-index: 1;
      -webkit-background-size: 50px 50px;
      -moz-background-size: 50px 50px;
      background-size: 50px 50px;
      -webkit-animation: move 2s linear infinite;
      -moz-animation: move 2s linear infinite;
      -webkit-border-top-right-radius: 8px;
      -webkit-border-bottom-right-radius: 8px;
      -moz-border-radius-topright: 8px;
      -moz-border-radius-bottomright: 8px;
      border-top-right-radius: 8px;
      border-bottom-right-radius: 8px;
      -webkit-border-top-left-radius: 20px;
      -webkit-border-bottom-left-radius: 20px;
      -moz-border-radius-topleft: 20px;
      -moz-border-radius-bottomleft: 20px;
      border-top-left-radius: 20px;
      border-bottom-left-radius: 20px;
      overflow: hidden;
  }
  .animate > span:after {
      display: none;
  }
  @-webkit-keyframes move {
      0% {
          background-position: 0 0;
      }
      100% {
          background-position: 50px 50px;
      }
  }
  @-moz-keyframes move {
      0% {
          background-position: 0 0;
      }
      100% {
          background-position: 50px 50px;
      }
  }
  .orange > span {
      background-color: #f1a165;
      background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #f1a165, #f36d0a);
      background-image: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0, #f1a165), color-stop(1, #f36d0a));
      background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(#f1a165, #f36d0a);
  }
  .red > span {
      background-color: #f0a3a3;
      background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #f0a3a3, #f42323);
      background-image: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0, #f0a3a3), color-stop(1, #f42323));
      background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(#f0a3a3, #f42323);
  }
  .nostripes > span > span, .nostripes > span:after {
      -webkit-animation: none;
      -moz-animation: none;
      background-image: none;
  }
```

```html
<div class="meter orange nostripes"> <span style="width: 33.3%"></span>

</div>
```

Also you can animated it if you want to use jquery:

```js
$(".meter > span").each(function() {
 $(this)
  .data("origWidth", $(this).width())
  .width(0)
  .animate({
   width: $(this).data("origWidth")
  }, 1200);
});
```

```css
  .meter {
      height: 40px;
      /* Can be anything */
      position: relative;
      margin: 60px 0 20px 0;
      /* Just for demo spacing */
      -moz-border-radius: 25px;
      -webkit-border-radius: 25px;
      border-radius: 25px;
      -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 -1px 1px rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.3);
      -moz-box-shadow : inset 0 -1px 1px rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.3);
      box-shadow : inset 0 -1px 1px rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.3);
      border: solid 1px orange;
  }
  .meter > span {
      display: block;
      height: 100%;
      -webkit-border-top-right-radius: 8px;
      -webkit-border-bottom-right-radius: 8px;
      -moz-border-radius-topright: 8px;
      -moz-border-radius-bottomright: 8px;
      border-top-right-radius: 8px;
      border-bottom-right-radius: 8px;
      -webkit-border-top-left-radius: 20px;
      -webkit-border-bottom-left-radius: 20px;
      -moz-border-radius-topleft: 20px;
      -moz-border-radius-bottomleft: 20px;
      border-top-left-radius: 20px;
      border-bottom-left-radius: 20px;
      background-color: rgb(43, 194, 83);
      background-image: -webkit-gradient(linear, left bottom, left top, color-stop(0, rgb(43, 194, 83)), color-stop(1, rgb(84, 240, 84)));
      background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(center bottom, rgb(43, 194, 83) 37%, rgb(84, 240, 84) 69%);
      -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 2px 9px rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.3), inset 0 -2px 6px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4);
      -moz-box-shadow: inset 0 2px 9px rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.3), inset 0 -2px 6px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4);
      box-shadow: inset 0 2px 9px rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.3), inset 0 -2px 6px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4);
      position: relative;
      overflow: hidden;
  }
  .meter > span:after, .animate > span > span {
      content:"";
      position: absolute;
      top: 0;
      left: 0;
      bottom: 0;
      right: 0;
      background-image: -webkit-gradient(linear, 0 0, 100% 100%, color-stop(.25, rgba(255, 255, 255, .2)), color-stop(.25, transparent), color-stop(.5, transparent), color-stop(.5, rgba(255, 255, 255, .2)), color-stop(.75, rgba(255, 255, 255, .2)), color-stop(.75, transparent), to(transparent));
      background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(-45deg, rgba(255, 255, 255, .2) 25%, transparent 25%, transparent 50%, rgba(255, 255, 255, .2) 50%, rgba(255, 255, 255, .2) 75%, transparent 75%, transparent);
      z-index: 1;
      -webkit-background-size: 50px 50px;
      -moz-background-size: 50px 50px;
      background-size: 50px 50px;
      -webkit-animation: move 2s linear infinite;
      -moz-animation: move 2s linear infinite;
      -webkit-border-top-right-radius: 8px;
      -webkit-border-bottom-right-radius: 8px;
      -moz-border-radius-topright: 8px;
      -moz-border-radius-bottomright: 8px;
      border-top-right-radius: 8px;
      border-bottom-right-radius: 8px;
      -webkit-border-top-left-radius: 20px;
      -webkit-border-bottom-left-radius: 20px;
      -moz-border-radius-topleft: 20px;
      -moz-border-radius-bottomleft: 20px;
      border-top-left-radius: 20px;
      border-bottom-left-radius: 20px;
      overflow: hidden;
  }
  .animate > span:after {
      display: none;
  }
  @-webkit-keyframes move {
      0% {
          background-position: 0 0;
      }
      100% {
          background-position: 50px 50px;
      }
  }
  @-moz-keyframes move {
      0% {
          background-position: 0 0;
      }
      100% {
          background-position: 50px 50px;
      }
  }
  .orange > span {
      background-color: #f1a165;
      background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #f1a165, #f36d0a);
      background-image: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0, #f1a165), color-stop(1, #f36d0a));
      background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(#f1a165, #f36d0a);
  }
  .red > span {
      background-color: #f0a3a3;
      background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #f0a3a3, #f42323);
      background-image: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0, #f0a3a3), color-stop(1, #f42323));
      background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(#f0a3a3, #f42323);
  }
  .nostripes > span > span, .nostripes > span:after {
      -webkit-animation: none;
      -moz-animation: none;
      background-image: none;
  }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="meter orange nostripes"> <span style="width: 33.3%"></span>

</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Here you go:

**http://jsfiddle.net/r0L0nty2/43/**

You must give the whole list a border instead of the list items. This is fixed with this code now.

```css
ul.quicktabs-tabs li {
height: 20px;
width:150px;
float: left;
background: transparent;
}

ul.quicktabs-tabs li a {
font-family: inherit;
margin: 0;
display: block; 
padding: 10px 27px 10px 7px;
text-decoration: none;
color: #6da648 !important;
margin: 0;
background:#fff;
}
ul.quicktabs-tabs li.active a { border-radius: 0 18px 18px 0;}
ul.quicktabs-tabs li.active a, ul.quicktabs-tabs li.active a:hover {
color: #fff !important;
background-position: right -20px;
    background: #6da648;
}
ul.quicktabs-tabs {
margin: 0 0 10px 0; 
 font-size: 11px; 
list-style: none;
padding: 0 0 34px 0;
border: 2px solid #6da648;
}
```

```html
<ul class="quicktabs-tabs">
    <li class="active"><a href="#">Item 1</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Item 2</a></li>
</ul>
```